# Why was the tattooist killed at the beginning of Ninja Assassin?

Tags: plot-explanation, ninja-assassin

The hero of the movie is a good guy and always punishes those who deserve punishment. However the tattooist in the very first scene of the movie seemed to be a good man. Despite that, He killed the tattooist. I could not understand why. Anybody has any explanation?

Here is the tattooist:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can not be sure if the tattooist was a good man just on the basis of one scene.
We don't know what he has done in the past to deserve that.
Also we know that the Ninja Assassin was more like a Hit-man working for the Ozunu clan. So it could also be that he killed the tattooist just because he was told to.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the impression that that was the hero ninja who killed the tattooist. The ninja who does it wore a mask.

As for why the other ninjas would kill him, mainly because they seem concerned with people in general knowing of their existence. And/or/less-reasonable, they had wanted to kill him before and hadn't realized they had failed.

Comment: Note that we don't see the women getting killed.

Comment: @SQB Ninja don't usually intentionally kill incidental people, do they?